# Extract a line with a string with double quote by using findstr

Tags: batch-file, findstr

First of all thank you for this site, I'm a terrible coder and so i need your help with making a batch script, i try to extract only lines that contains Copy " in that line from a text file by using findstr which actually works without that whitespace and double quote. But it will extract the line with "Copy and Help" too which i don't need.

Example:

My text contains (source.txt)

```
a
asd Copy and help with these command prompt:
a
  asd Copy "c:\.." a b c(white space)
a
 asd Copy and help with these command prompt:
Copy "d:\.." a c c(tab space)
avs
    Copy "e:\.." a a c
vvddf
```

Output file (op.txt) (should be)

```
Copy "c:\.." a b c
Copy "d:\.." a c c
Copy "e:\.." a a c
```

After my original code I tried to use

```
findstr /c:"Copy ^"" > op.txt
```

but this doesn't work. To let the findstr know to search a line containing

```
Copy "
```

Copy[whitespace][double quote]

***Updated section***

First off my required batch script is working from help by foxidrive. There is still some tweak to do, but i will post it as another question. This question is answered.

This is my updated code for now.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET source="details.txt"
IF EXIST %source% (
  FIND /i "copy " <%source% |FIND "\" >op.txt
) ELSE (
  Exit
)
```

Thanks foxidrive for the start off and solving my first issue.

*Sorry for my English, it's poor like my coding*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic solution is to use this

```
find ":\" <source.txt  >op.txt
```

Or this is another workaround:

```
find ":\" <source.txt |find /i "copy " >op.txt
```

Comment: I do apologize about my not more detailed text version, my text version with the "Copy and help..." has also a colon (:) in the line aswell. So i tried to use /c:"Copy ^"" but this doesn't work. To let the findstr know to search a line containing Copy "

Comment: After some tries i got it worked with your suggestion
find /i "copy " <%source% |find "\" >op.txt
and also worked with
find ":\" <source.txt |find /i "copy " >op.txt

Comment: Is it ok to use find /i "copy " <%source% |find "\" >op.txt ?

Comment: That's good.  Yes you can search either string first and your syntax looks ok.  Enclose `%source%` in double quotes if you use long filenames or pathnames or `&` in the name.

Comment: SET source="details.txt" , will update my main post to let you see my updated code. And foxidrive, thank you for helping me i really appriciate your help here. *sorry my English isn't that good like my coding*.

Comment: Thanks.  If you want to accept the answer then click the grey tick next to it.  It lets others know in the future that an answer is worth trying, and it gives you, and me, extra Stack Overflow reputation.

Comment: But there is still a little tweak to do i try to post the updated code but can't post in into the code box. (what a fail i am)

Comment: StackOverflow works on a policy of a question and a related answer.  If your question changes then please open a new question, with the changed title and information.