# To extract multiple lines with find, trim lead and trail spaces

Tags: batch-file, find, trim

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272357/solvedbatch-scriptextract-a-line-with-a-string-with-double-quote-by-using-fi) was to extract multiple lines from a text files, which is working fine now but it still needs some improve to trim leading and trailing(tricky part) whitespaces/tab spaces and from searching thru Stackoverflow i found many answers and let me combine my final batch-script but from all putting it together it could be not that *right*.

Details.txt (source file)

```
line not needed, Copy and help with these command prompt:
line not needed:
(whitespace)(whitespace)some text not needed Copy "c:\.." a b c(white space)
line not needed:
line not needed, Copy and help with these command prompt:
(whitespace)Copy "d:\.." a c c(tab space)
line not needed
(tab space)(tab space)Copy "e:\.." a a c(whitespace)
line not needed
```

op.txt (Output file)

```
Copy "c:\.." a b c
Copy "d:\.." a c c
Copy "e:\.." a a c
```

Let's see the first batch-script. (without trim lead and trail spaces)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET source="details.txt"
IF EXIST %source% (
  FIND /i "copy " <%source% |FIND "\" >op.txt
) ELSE (
  Exit
)
```

The combined script to trim lead and trail spaces which gives me two outputs(not big deal). But if we can shorten it both in output and code would be great.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET source="details.txt"
IF EXIST %source% (
  FIND /i "copy " <%source% |FIND "\" >op.txt
  >op2.txt (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (op.txt) DO (
      SET "ln=%%A"
      SET str=!ln:*Copy=Copy!
      FOR /l %%b IN (1,1,31) DO (
        IF "!str:~-1!"==" " SET str=!str:~0,-1!
        IF "!str:~-1!"=="   " SET str=!str:~0,-1!
      )
      ECHO !str!
    )
  )
) ELSE (
  Exit
)
```

It actually works in my most situation of source files but I'm sure that this could be not well coded. So i would to ask to improve this batch-script in some ways like output or maybe a shorter/easier version.

Thanks, foxidrive for the start off and helping to solve at my first problem.

***Updated version from David*** (Now with all output)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourceFile=details.txt"
SET "outputFile=opDavid.txt"
@ECHO OFF > "%outputFile%"
IF EXIST "%sourceFile%" FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('FIND /i "copy " ^<%sourceFile% ^|FIND "\"') DO CALL :Trim %%A >>%outputFile%
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b 0

:Trim
ECHO(%*
EXIT /b 0
```

*Sorry for my English, it's poor like my coding*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This will do what you want, but with restrictions.

- The following "poison" characters must not be in the string: | < > & ^ %

The `Trim` routine works by using the `call` command to trim any leading and trailing white spaces.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "source=details.txt"
SET "output=op.txt"
@echo off > "%output%"
IF EXIST "%source%" FOR /f "delims=" %%A in ('FIND /i "copy " ^<%source% ^|FIND "\"') do call :Trim %%A >> "%output%"
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b 0

:Trim
echo(%*
EXIT /b 0
```

#### Update to answer questions from the comments

- **Restriction Reasons:**

  - `| < > &` will cause the script to crash unless inside quotations or escaped correctly with `^`.
  - `^` will be removed from the string unless inside quotations because it is the escape char unless it itself is escaped.
  - `%` will be removed from the string even inside quotations because it is the variable char unless it itself is escaped `%%`.
  - Note that each of these character has to be escaped for each time cmd parses them which can become a major pain in the.
  - [Batch Special Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- There are other complicated situations which require an understanding of how cmd works.  **[Read These Answers!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

*NOTE that most of these restrictions can be handled but it requires several more lines of code and then there might still be some restrictions.* [See My FindAndReplace.bat proof of concept for a look into what it would take.](https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/4608317)

The quotations surround the variable and value `set "var=value"` are there to provide special character protection without having to put quotations in the value itself.

- *My General Batch String Rule (And I believe the Batch Community Agrees)*: Avoid surrounding quotations within variable values and quote variables when used.

This prevents scenarios where a variable has quotations and is in quotations.  This below will fail since the

```
set var="value with spaces"
if "%var%"="value with spaces"
:: this becomes
if ""value with spaces""="value with spaces"
```

`ENDLOCAL` closes the scope from the `SETLOCAL` command, therefore, cleaning up all the changes made to the environment. [See This Reference](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)

Comment: This is awesome, the script how you shorten it down so short. I tested your script and it worked but it shows only the last line, so may i change from ">op.txt" to ">>op.txt" and add ">nul copy nul %outputFile%" to create a clean file on start and to get all needed lines. Please take a look on my updated script. And thank you again David. :)

Comment: I have three question. May i ask what the restrictions are be that you mention? And could you please explain me about the SET "source=details.txt" why it has double quotes around source=details.txt instead of only the path or filename ? And does ENDLOCAL from *IF EXIST* just work like that instead of *ELSE* ?

Comment: @DoubleQuotes I updated my answer to address your questions.  Also, I added another example of how to null a file. `@echo off > "%output%"`

Comment: On process to follow up your answers now. Thank you very much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you put two helper batch files in your path, then this command will work without needing to install any third party software:

```
type "source.txt" |repl "^[ \t]*" "" |repl "[ \t]*$" "" |findrepl "copy \x22" /i >op.txt
```

The first two `repl` commands remove leading and then trailing whitespace of space/tab and the `findrepl` command will filter lines that have `copy "` in them.

The helper batch file called `repl.bat` can be found [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855)
The helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` can be found [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697)

Put them both in the same folder as the batch file, or in c:\windows\system32 or another directory that is on the PATH statement.

Comment: Prefer to use without a helper batch for this time.(it's a very effective script what i have read, nice). Thanks foxidrive, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just try [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//" details.txt
```